# Visio graphics service

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure, visio, visio-services

Is it possible to add a **trusted data providers** to the **Visio graphics service**
on **SharePoint Online**?

I wish to display a Visio diagram with a connection to SQL Azure on SharePoint Online but I get this error:

> Visio Services was unable to refresh external data connections in this Web Drawing because one or more data provider required by these connections is not trusted by the Visio Graphics Service. To resolve this issue, ask your system administrator to add the data providers you need to refresh this Web Drawing to the Trusted Data Providers list of the Visio Graphics Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint online at this time is not supporting the SQL azure as datasource. here is MSFT note on it.

> Visio Services does not support SQL, SQL Azure, OLEDC, ODBC, and
>   custom data providers as data sources in SharePoint Online.

Read more from here: [Visio Services in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164027%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: so can I refresh just list and excel data sources? So sad